# Ionic4 + Angular: dynamically creating ion-select with *ngFor results in linking all ion-select-options together (unintentionally)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I need to create a list of `ion-select` based on an array inside an object called `myObject.array`.

- When I create the list using `mypage.page.ts` and `mypage.page.html`
  code listed below. All my `ion-select-options` get linked together -
  so when I change one `ion-select` to `Y` all ion-select changes to
  `Y` etc.
- I can see in my console log that `ionChange` is fired up only once -
  ale inside it I can also see correct data (that only one item inside
  a myObject.array is changed).
- The problem is that UI doesn't correspond with the data inside the `mypage.page.ts`

Picture below shows UI after I change only one `ion-select` and console log (you can see that multiple `ion-select` changed and the console log data doesn't correspond with the UI):

[image]

### How can I create `ion-selects` dynamically from an array and don't link them with eachother?

Edit:

- The errors in the console are related to cookies (with this error message : `Indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by specifying its SameSite attribute`).
- The errors are unrelated to my code because whether I add the page or delete it they are still there.

My code:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>mypage</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let output of myObject.array;let i=index;">
    <ion-label> Array object {{i}}</ion-label>
      <ion-select
      [(ngModel)]="myObject.array[i]"
      (ionChange)="change($event, i)"
      okText="Set" cancelText="Throw away">
        <ion-select-option value="Y"> Yes? </ion-select-option>
        <ion-select-option value="N"> No? </ion-select-option>
      </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

And this `mypage.page.ts` code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mypage',
  templateUrl: './mypage.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mypage.page.scss'],
})
export class MypagePage implements OnInit {

  myObject = {array: ['Y','Y','Y']};

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  change(event, i){
    console.log(event);
    console.log(i);
    console.log(this.myObject);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`trackBy` is something made to improve change detection performance.

Just for the record here's how one make it "trackBy" index:

**Template change**

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let output of myObject.array; let i=index; trackBy:indexTracker;">
```

**Controller change**

```
indexTracker(index: number, value: any) {
    return index;
}
```

Comment: Do I now change the values of `myObject.array` inside the `indexTracker`? Or what is the functionality behind it.

Comment: On each `ngDoCheck` triggered for the `ngForOf` directive, Angular checks what objects have changed. It uses differs for this process and each differ uses the `trackBy` function to compare the current object with the new one. The default `trackBy` function tracks items by identity.

Comment: You don't need to change anything, just add them as it is

Comment: Thank you a lot! I will read some docs on `trackBy` more so I can understand it fully - just last mini question - if I have multiple `*ngFor` in my page - I do need to use multiple trackers right?

Comment: yes just add `trackBy:indexTracker;` for each ngFor

Comment: But do I need to create `indexTracker2` function or not? For each *ngFor? Or I can use one function `indexTracker` for all `*ngFor`?

Comment: Same function can be used, no need to create another in same controller